# Selenium не хочет кликать по выпадающему списку

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Задача кликнуть Sekenium по списку, но как это сделать? Есть поле ник, туда передается значение "aldassa" и если оно есть в базе то
предлагается выбрать из списка. Вот по этому списку и нужно кликнуть, на любое из представленного
[image: картинка]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

nick=driver.find_element_by_name('yid')
nick.send_keys('aldassa')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(nick).click(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.desktop-suggestions-container')).perform()
```

[image: код с сайта]
Ошибку не выдает, но кликать не хочет. Пробовал делать так, но результата нету. Как это правильно сделать?

```
nick=driver.find_element_by_name('yid')
nick.send_keys('aldassa')
offer_nick = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.desktop-suggestions-container')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(nick).click(offer_nick).perform()
```

Может надо дождаться загрузки страницы?

Comment: Я когда делал похожую задачу использовал XPath, он забирает со страницы по идентификатору элемент и отдает селениуму для обработки. UPD. Я бы еще добавил в li в атрибуты идентификаторы каждого варианта выбора, по нему можно и выбирать элемент

Comment: код не работает из-за связки последнего firefox и selenium. переделал под хром и все заработало!